# orderBy and filter inside the same ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-orderby

I have a table on which is implement sorting on columns and filter after a column (type).

It works fine if I use either `orderBy` or `filter` but does not work ( there is no data showed in the table) if there are both in `ng-repeat`.

This is the code:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="rows in $ctrl.myData |
     orderBy:$ctrl.sort.active:$ctrl.sort.descending track by $index |
     filter: {Type:type} track by $index"
 >
```

If I use like this it works the filter:

```
<tr ng-repeat="rows in $ctrl.myData | filter: {Type:type} track by $index">
```

and like this it works the ordering:

```
<tr ng-repeat="rows in $ctrl.myData | orderBy:$ctrl.sort.active:$ctrl.sort.descending track by $index">
```

Why isn't it work for both?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is caused by the presence of two `track by $index`.

Changing it to

```
<tr ng-repeat="rows in $ctrl.myData|   
    orderBy:$ctrl.sort.active:$ctrl.sort.descending |        
    filter: {Type:type} track by $index"
>
```

solved the problem.